# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: props for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to get my head around groovy scripting to make some changes to a jenkins pipeline and I keep getting this error:

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: props for class: groovy.lang.Binding

I have tried declaring the variable with def but I still get the exception

```
 pipeline {
    agent any
        stages {
            stage('Build'){
            steps {
                script {
                    // env.application_servers = 'sl2o2xbar01;sl2o2xbar02'
                    def hb_parameters = []
                    if (env.application_servers.length() > 0)  {
                        if (env.hb_job_params.length() > 0){    
                        try {
                            //env.hb_job_params
                            /*
                            {
                                "sl2o2xbar01": {
                                    "ENV": "DEV",
                                    "dev_xbar_host": "sl2o2xbar01"
                                },
                                    "sl2o2xbar02": {
                                    "ENV": "DEV",
                                    "dev_xbar_host": "sl2o2xbar0"
                                }
                            }
                            */
                            def props =  readJSON text: env.hb_job_params
                            //props = ['sl2o2xbar01':['ENV':'DEV', 'dev_xbar_host':'sl2o2xbar01'], 'sl2o2xbar02':['ENV':'DEV', 'dev_xbar_host':'sl2o2xbar02']]
                            def hb_job_application_servers = props.keySet()
                            echo "${props}"
                            } catch(e) {
                            echo "Caught: ${e} JSON not valid."
                            currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                            }   
                        }
                        application_servers_list = env.application_servers.split(';')
                        for( String application_server : application_servers_list ){
                            
                            if (
                                env.application_services_list.contains('heartbeat_consumer') &&
                                props.get(application_server)
                            ){
                                for ( param in props.get(application_server)) {
                                    hb_parameters.add([$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: ${param.key}, value: ${param.value}])
                                }
                                echo hb_parameters
                                echo "triggering heartbeat_consumer build"
                                build job: "dvmt30-realm-monitor", wait: false, parameters: hb_parameters
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude, did you even look at the problem I described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of the variable *props* is inside the try-catch:

```
try {
    def props =  readJSON text: env.hb_job_params
    ...
}
```

But later, you try to use it in `props.get(application_server)` and that variable does not exist anymore at that point